# how to get a bool in a stateful widget to change a counter in it's parent stateful widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm quite new to flutter and i'm struggling to get my head around passing variables up the widget tree. I've written a very simple code to demonstrate what i'm trying to achieve and I was hoping someone could please spell it out for me.

I have a parent Stateful widget with a counter in it:

```
class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ParentWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ParentWidget> createState() => _ParentWidgetState();
}

class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  int Counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 100,
            ),
            Button(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

then I have another Stateful Widget with the button and bool in it:

```
class Button extends StatefulWidget {
  const Button({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Button> createState() => _ButtonState();
}

class _ButtonState extends State<Button> {
  bool buttonPressed = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          buttonPressed = !buttonPressed;
          print(buttonPressed);
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        color: kWhite,
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've looked at some of the other answers (using callbacks?) but am struggling to understand how it actually works and how I would implement it into my code

How do I pass the bool variable up the tree to change the counter?

thanks so much and any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the callback function in the `Button` widget that returns the state of the button pressed.

In `Parent` widget, add the argument for the callback function which returns the button pressed state.

```html
class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ParentWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ParentWidget> createState() => _ParentWidgetState();
}

class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  int Counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 100,
            ),
            Button(isPressed: (isPressed) => print(isPressed)),  <-- updated
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```html
class Button extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(bool) isPressed;   <-- updated

  const Button({Key? key, required this.isPressed}) : super(key: key);   <-- updated

  @override
  State<Button> createState() => _ButtonState();
}

class _ButtonState extends State<Button> {
  bool buttonPressed = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          buttonPressed = !buttonPressed;
          print(buttonPressed);
        });
         widget.isPressed(buttonPressed);  <-- updated
      },
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. but how do i make it increase/ decrease the counter in the parent widget? cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is how to pass data to parent widget using a callback,

```
class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ParentWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ParentWidget> createState() => _ParentWidgetState();
}

class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  int Counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 100,
            ),
            Button(
              // here you will get the bool
              onBtnPressed: (val) {
                print(val);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Button extends StatefulWidget {
  const Button({required this.onBtnPressed, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // add this here, this function will act as the callback
  final Function onBtnPressed;

  @override
  State<Button> createState() => _ButtonState();
}

class _ButtonState extends State<Button> {
  bool buttonPressed = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          buttonPressed = !buttonPressed;
          print(buttonPressed);
        });
        widget.onBtnPressed(buttonPressed);
      },
      child: Container(
        color: kWhite,
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use `ValueChanged<bool>` instead of `Function`, Function is too broad

Comment: Agreed, I preferred Function since the author was struggling to understand how callbacks work.